# is there a way to search for keywords, past and present, in a (svn) subversion repository

Tags: svn, search, tortoisesvn, keyword

Although a subversion repository is like a time machine where nothing is ever deleted. i still find myself reluctant to totally 'svn delete' things from my codebase if i think i might want to search for it at a later date.

So, i will feel freer if i could have some way of keeping a local-copy index of the keywords and phrases in the repository. So if i search for, say "ImportantDepracatedClass" then i could see results of what is in my code base and also what used to be in my code base.

Is there some way of doing this?

I use SVN Tortoise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may (or may not) be of help to you: [svnquery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/)